# How to throttle Kafka Consumer on the basis of QPS to be supported?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

**Use Case :** 
Consume Data from Kafka, and then write to a DB which is bound by a max QPS.

**Predicted solution :**
throttle the rate of consumption to a limit which is less the max write QPS of the DB.

**Query**:
Guava gives a rate limiter which can be implemented here, but does Kafka supports consumer rate limiting itself rather than implementing third party options.

**References** for features on Kafka Rate Limiting : 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-13+-+Quotas

Also, how can the quota rate limiting can be applied in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to use third-party libraries. 
Google's [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.java) is the best and the easiest one to use.

For sample codes, regarding the usage of Guava Rate Limiter, please refer [this](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-rate-limiter)